# What is wrong with the 2D list i try to update?

Tags: python-3.x

I make a 2D list:

```
list1 = []
liste = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(93):
    list1.append(liste)
```

And then try to update the elements in one of them by:

```
stemmer_tall = [123, 3321, 3442, 23, 1]

for i in range(5):
    list1[0][i] += stemmer_tall[i]
```

When I do it, it updates not just the first list in my list, but all of them. What is wrong here? I cant figure it out.

EDIT: I want a list with 92 lists inside it, with just have zeroes. But the first list should be [123, 3321, 3442, 23, 1].

Comment: What is the expected output?  What should the resulting list look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same reference to the list every time.
So each item in `list1` points to the same `liste` variable.

You could make a new copy of the array. It would look like this:

```
list1 = []
liste = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(93):
    list1.append(liste.copy())

stemmer_tall = [123, 3321, 3442, 23, 1]
for i in range(5):
    list1[0][i] += stemmer_tall[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You append the same list over and over again. In python, when you create a list as

```
liste = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`liste` is essentially a reference to the list you just created. Then, when you append this reference over and over again to another list as

```
list1 = []
for i in range(93):
    list1.append(liste)
```

you append the same reference over and over again; but they all point to the same list. If you want to create different lists, then you should create different lists:

```
list1 = []
for i in range(93):
    list1.append([0]*5)
```

Now, if you change one of the lists, the others won't change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add each list element in `stemmer_tall` individually.  You can simply assign it to the first list in `list1`:

```
list1 = []
liste = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(93):
    list1.append(liste)

stemmer_tall = [123, 3321, 3442, 23, 1]
list1[0] = stemmer_tall
```

**Output** (Tested with Repl.it)

```
[123, 3321, 3442, 23, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

(etc)